# Proof that $\mathbb{F}_p[t] / \mathbb{F}_p[t^p]$ is not a separable field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

The book I'm working with shows that $\mathbb{F}_p[t] / \mathbb{F}_p[t^p]$ is not a separable field extension by saying that the polynomial $X^p-t$ is irreducible (because of Eisenstein) and that is not separable because of $f' = p X^{p-1} = 0$.

---

I understand that the polynomial is not separable and that it is irreducible. But why does that imply that the field extension is not separable?

We defined a field extension $L/K$ as separable iff every element in $L$ is separable, i.e. iff the minimal polynomial of it is separable.

But which element of $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ has the minimal polynomial $X^p-t \in \mathbb{F}_p[t^p][X]$?

And also, $X^p-t$ is not even an element of $\mathbb{F}_p[t^p][X]$.

**Edit:** Typo, I meant $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ always

Comment: The polynomial should be $X^p-t^p$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I think I got it now. Can you please check my own answer if I understand this correctly now?

Comment: As others have pointed out, $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ is a ring but not a field. $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ is a field (generated freely by $t$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the text means to say $\mathbb{F}_p(t) $ and not $\mathbb{F}_p[t] $.

We denote $t^p\in\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ as $u$.

Extending $K=\mathbb{F}_p(u)$ to $K'=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$

is the same as extending $K$ to $K''=\dfrac{K[x]}{\langle x^p-u\rangle}$.

Let $t''$ be the image of $x$ under the canonical homomorphism $K[x]\to\dfrac{K[x]}{\langle x^p-u\rangle}$.

The minimal polynomial of $t''\in K''$ with coefficients in $K$

is $f(y)=y^p-u\in K[y]$, which is not separable.

Comment: Can you explain why extending $K$ to $K'$ is the same as extending $K$ to $K''$?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

---

The minimal polynomial of $t \in \mathbb{F}_p(t)$ is $f = X^p-t^p \in \mathbb{F}_p(t^p)[X]$ since $f(t) = 0$ and $f$ is irreducible because of Eisenstein: $t^p \in \mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$ is irreducible and thus prime, and $t^p$ doesn't devide $1$ and $(t^p)^2$ doesn't devide $t^p$.

But $f$ it is not separable. Furthermore, it is totally inseparable since with Frobenius we see $f = (X-t)^p \in \mathbb{F}_p(t)[X]$.

Comment: You need a different argument for irreducibility, since $t^p$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb F_p(t^p)$ due to $\mathbb F_p(t^p)$ being a field (fields do not contain irreducible elements). You can use Frobenius, though: no nontrivial factor of $(X-t)^p$ is contained in $\mathbb F_p(t^p)[X]$.